# How to use host machine as an agent from Jenkins running in a docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431612/jenkins-through-docker-how-to-configure-own-host-as-agent-for-jenkins), but not getting my required solution.
I'm running Jenkins inside a docker image (from https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins). And now want to use my host (Windows 10) machine as an agent or slave, so that some jobs required to be executed on the Windows machine can use my host machine. This job includes the use of another docker container.

First, I don't know how to access the host from inside Docker. So I'm unable to figure out the addresses/ip to use in Manage Jenkin's Nodes.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Add the host machine as node with the IP address  In conatiner(Jenkins) .
Then on each Job you can  restrict the job to run on specific slave (respected node of host machine ).

Answer (score 0):

See this command will help you to solve your problem :

```
docker run -d --name my-jenkins \
 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home  \
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
 -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000  \
 jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```